# no logro cambiar el nombre de mi aplicación

Tags: android, android-studio

Quiero cambiar el nombre de mi aplicación Android, he probado muchas cosas que he encontrado por la red,y solo he conseguido cambiar el nombre del proyecto, de hecho en el proyecto no hay rastro del nombre antiguo, pero al generar la aplicación resultante sigue saliendo el nombre anterior.

Pongo el android manifest:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/map3"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/map3"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.pc08.SetOfTracks.MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Muchas gracias!!

Comment: Has modificado el valor del string app_name en el archivo strings.xml?

Comment: Sí, también lo cambié y nada.

Comment: @MartíAmatVila =/ Estabas editando otro archivo! que tienes dentro de strings.xml y app_name ? Me parece que modificaste algo al cambiar  android:name=

Answer (score 5, accepted):

has probado colocar el nombre directamente como una cadena de texto en la propiedad label.

Por ejemplo:

```
<application
...
android:label="Nombre de la app"
...
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! Funcionó!

Comment: Se puede realizar pero en la documentación indica: android:label , La etiqueta se debe establecer como una referencia a un recurso de cadena, por lo que se puede localizar como otras cadenas en la interfaz de usuario.

Answer (score 2):

No debes cambiar esta propiedad si deseas cambiar el nombre de tu aplicacion:

```
<activity
            android:name="com.example.pc08.SetOfTracks.MainActivity"
```

incluso puede provocar tu aplicación no funcione si el paquete definido es incorrecto.

La propiedad correcta para cambiar el nombre de tu aplicación es:

```
 <application
        ...
        ...
        android:label="@string/app_name"
```

---

**Para cambiar el nombre de tu aplicación**, revisa la referencia del string definido en la propiedad [android:label](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#label) :

```
android:label="@string/app_name"
```

dentro de tu proyecto ve al folder `/res/values/` ahi encontraras el archivo `strings.xml` que contiene el string con el nombre `"app_name"`, ahí es donde puedes modificar el nombre de tu aplicación.

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">Nombre de aplicacion</string>
    ...
    ...
</resources>
```

También puedes definir directamente el nombre de la aplicación:

```
<application
...
android:label=Nombre de aplicacion
...
```

Aunque la [documentación](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html#label) indica:

[**android:label**](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html#label) La etiqueta se debe establecer como una referencia a un recurso de cadena, por lo que se puede localizar como otras cadenas en la interfaz de usuario.

Comment: Gracias, esto ya lo cambié y tampoco funcionó.

Comment: Asegura lo realizaste en el folder que se encuentra dentro de /app . Si aseguras lo anterior realiza un Clean de tu proyecto.

Comment: Hola Jorge, gracias por tu información, como viste logré el resultado que buscaba cambiando directamente el android:label, casualemente ( o no) 
 ahora no se cargan los mapas de googlemaps, puede tener algo que ver?Cambié la apikey y nada.

Comment: Hola @MartíAmatVila No se si fuiste tu quien me dió calificación negativa pero lo mejor es tener concentrados los Strings dentro del archivo strings.xml **si funcionaba antes y ahora no es porque seguramente modificaste android:name o dentro del build.gradle el valor de applicationId, estos valores NO deben modificarse para cambiar el nombre de la aplicación.** , No se ve tu mapa porque cuando habilitas la API creas una llave que esta relacionada con tu Keystore y con el applicationId  (package name), si este último cambio no se mostraría el mapa.

Comment: no fuí yo el de el voto negativo, solo tengo 10 puntos, con esto no puedo ni calificar...jejeje

Comment: Gracia solo queria cambiar el nombre para poner dos palabras esto fue lo que use.. dentro de tu proyecto ve al folder /res/values/ ahi encontraras el archivo strings.xml que contiene el string con el nombre "app_name", ahí es donde puedes modificar el nombre de tu aplicación.

Answer (score 1):

el nombre de la app en el manifest debe coincidir con el del gradle:
`build.gradle(Module:app) applicationId "nombre de la app aquí"`

Comment: Gracias, lo comprobé y tb tenia el nombre actua lizado correctamentr

Comment: applicationId define el id de aplicación o packageid pero no su nombre.

Answer (score 0):

A mi me funciono simplemente con poner el nombre en la activity principal, espero te sirva, saludos

```
<application
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@mipmap/map3"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:roundIcon="@mipmap/map3"
android:supportsRtl="true"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
<activity
    android:name="com.example.pc08.SetOfTracks.MainActivity"
    android:label="AQUI VA EL NOMBRE TU APLICACION"

    android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo cambias en la carpeta Res - Values - Strings.xml la etiqueta

```
<string name="app_name">Nombre de tu aplicacion</string>
```